# Django: a simple way to group and count objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'd like to do something really simple but don't find the way to do it.

models.py:

```
class Reward:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # other stuff

class UseRewardEvent:
    reward = models.ForeignKey(Reward)
    # other stuff
```

In the end, I'd like to print a table with reward name and the amount of events with this reward name.

*For example*:

if UseRewardEvent.objets.all() contains 3 objects whose linked reward.name is:

- "free chicken"
- "free chicken"
- "free rabbit"

and Reward.objects.all() contains 3 objects whose name is :

- "free chicken"
- "free rabbit"
- "free cow"

This should print in my template a table containing used rewards like:

- free chicken -> 2
- free rabbit -> 1
- free cow -> 0 (because there is no UseRewardEvent with reward.name equals 'free cow')

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/) is for.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Reward.objects.annotate(use_count=Count('userewardevent'))
```

Comment: This returns a list of all the rewards. But where are stored information about the number of uses? (ie. 2, 1, and 0 if I use my example) ? Thx.

Comment: That is what `use_count` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
for reward in Reward.objects.all():
    print reward,'->',len(reward.userewardevent_set.all())
```

used in template

```
{% for reward in Reward.objects.all %}
<p>{{ reward }} --> {{ reward.userewardevent_set.all|length }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

use **reward.userewardevent_set** to get relevant information, It is a RelatedManager, acts as **reward.objects**

**More efficient according to Daniel Roseman**,thx!

```
for reward in Reward.objects.all():
    print reward,'->',reward.userewardevent_set.count()
```

used in template

```
{% for reward in Reward.objects.all %}
<p>{{ reward }} --> {{ reward.userewardevent_set.count }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this will give you the answer, it is extremely inefficient in terms of database access. (And you should almost always use `.count()`, not `len()`, on querysets.)